# pre-receive hook declined (Gitlab)

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

My school offers me a Gitlab account so we can host our projects.

I am the owner, so i can do everything with my project. If somebody push code to my project, can i review the code before pushing it to the server?

When i make them "Master" they push code to my project without letting me review.

If i make them "Developer i get this strange error and they cant push:

```
(pre-receive hook declined)
```

Some i am asking, why cant they push if i make them "Developer" and can i change some settings so that i need to review the code before pushing it?

Thanks.

Youri

Comment: Your hook may have exit with a non-zero value. What does your hook look like?

Comment: @joran Where can i find this "Hook"?

Comment: sorry, missed that you using GitLab, see my answer for GitLab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default is the master branch protected in GitLab, "Developers" does not have permission to push to master.

You may find how you administrate the privacy of branches here http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/workflow/protected_branches.html

GitLab supports comments on committed changes for feedback to the author, also, GitLab supports "merge request" which allows you to preview code before you merge it into master, see https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/.

Comment: Oke thanks, so you are saying before somebody is going to push code, i can review the code as owner? Before pushing it to the server?

Comment: @Yooouuri, I have update my answer with how you can review code in GitLab. Collaborators must push their code somewhere before you can review it, where to depends on your setup and workflow.